# Is there a restriction on how low one can set the deployment target when submitting to the app store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have about a 200+ iPads (1st generation), that my company uses. They work fine (like new).

The latest version of Xcode only lets you set a deployment target of 8.0.
I can download an older version of Xcode that lets me set a deployment target of 5.0 (for 1st generation iPad).

If I set the deployment target to 5.0, and submit via an older version of Xcode, will I have a problem submitting to the app store ? Is there any restriction on how low one can set the deployment target when submitting ?

Comment: You will try to upload with Application Loader to submit app on appstore.

Answer (score 1):

The current App Distribution Guide says "For example, the lowest available setting for iPad apps is iOS 4.3." ( Setting the Deployment Target ) but my Xcode 7.1.1 doesn't seem to allow any deployment target for an iPhone project to be lower than iOS 6.0. So YMMV I guess. Basically the minimum is whatever the minimum supported Xcode version (Is Xcode 5 still allowed or does the store now require Xcode 6? I don't know) allows in the popup for the project deployment target.

One other factor - if you use Swift that limits you to iOS 7.0 and later.

Please check guideline below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW21